# ADB server crashes when phone connected

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to develop an app for iOS and Android on a Mac. Everything good so far on the iOS side, but I can't connect the Android device (Samsung Galaxy S21 and Samsung Galaxy Tab A8) to my Mac. ADB crashes every time I connect that phone to it with the following output:

```
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
ADB server didn't ACK
Full server startup log: /var/folders/2h/n5j5dyd52bx0032j5zkhb_fc0000gp/T//adb.502.log
Server had pid: 15806
--- adb starting (pid 15806) ---
adb I 06-14 11:29:22 15806 122251 main.cpp:63] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
adb I 06-14 11:29:22 15806 122251 main.cpp:63] Version 34.0.3-10161052
adb I 06-14 11:29:22 15806 122251 main.cpp:63] Installed as /Users/ahumeniy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
adb I 06-14 11:29:22 15806 122251 main.cpp:63] Running on Darwin 22.5.0 (x86_64)
adb I 06-14 11:29:22 15806 122251 main.cpp:63] 
adb I 06-14 11:29:22 15806 122254 usb_osx.cpp:325] reported max packet size for R5CR70H8CMH is 512
adb I 06-14 11:29:22 15806 122251 auth.cpp:416] adb_auth_init...
adb I 06-14 11:29:22 15806 122251 auth.cpp:152] loaded new key from '/Users/ahumeniy/.android/adbkey' with fingerprint E4AB9FB40094FFB853F84255E3CD2D56D64508DB42BA4DE9D97ED06C3ED3E59C
adb I 06-14 11:29:22 15806 122258 transport.cpp:307] R5CR70H8CMH: write thread spawning
adb I 06-14 11:29:22 15806 122257 transport.cpp:335] R5CR70H8CMH: read thread spawning
adb I 06-14 11:29:22 15806 122251 transport.cpp:1727] fetching keys for transport R5CR70H8CMH
adb I 06-14 11:29:22 15806 122251 auth.cpp:468] Calling send_auth_response
adb I 06-14 11:29:22 15806 122251 adb.cpp:177] R5CR70H8CMH: offline

* failed to start daemon
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

The error don't happen when working on either Linux or Windows, only in this machine.

Previously this machine was used to develop an .NET MAUI project, but now it's used for a Flutter app. I believe uninstalling the Microsoft Android SDK went wrong somehow or it has some conflict.

This machine is using OpenCore-patcher because it's a mid-2015 Macbook Pro which has no support for Mac OS Ventura, required for development on iPhones with the latest updates, so I had to force the update.

Launching ADB alone will bring up the server and when I connect the device it is listed for a second before the ADB server crashes. I tried the same devices on Android and Windows and it works well. I haven't tried on another Mac because I don't have one nearby.